# There is no empty project section in Xcode 6.1.1?

Tags: ios, xcode

I need to create a new empty application. When i used xcode version 6.0 , it was ok, but now because of version of 6.1.1 , it does not seen in the Create new project/İOS/Application! Therefore, what should i do , guys? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why does it need to be empty? Create the closest one and delete the parts you don't need.

Answer (score 1):

Empty Project has been moved to other section,See Snapshot:[image]

Answer (score 0):

Empty projects now are located in the section "Other".

Comment: yeah, but for the old one , there was AppDelegate file or any things , new one does not have for all these, namely ,it's really empty , is there any preference or setting?

Comment: @legolas create a "single view" project or something. That leaves you with a couple of files to delete and you're done.